# "Sono [professione]" è corretto?

Tags: articles

- Sono un professore
- Sono un dottore
- Sono un insegnate

sono frasi corrette.

Lo sono anche se si omette l'articolo?
e.g.

- Sono professore
- Sono dottore
- Sono giornalista

è una costruzione che vedo spesso utilizzata, ma mi chiedevo se ci fosse una regola a riguardo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE nel suo [decimo anniversario](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1489/707)!

Comment: Potresti rispondere a "Che lavoro fai?" (per esempio) con "Sono professore [all'Istituto Tecnico Benedetto Castelli]." È una risposta corretta.